# How to validate ask password confirmation code wso2 SCIM 2 API

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am using SCIM api for registering a user

```
curl -v -k --user admin:admin --data '{"schemas":[],"name":{"familyName":"Smith","givenName":"Paul"},"userName":"Paul","password":"password","emails":[{"primary":true,"value":"paul@somemail.com"}],"urn:ietf:params:scim:schemas:extension:enterprise:2.0:User":{askPassword:"true"}}' --header "Content-Type:application/json" https://localhost:9443/scim2/Users
```

I got a

> Create Password for New Account

email to my primary email address with a confirmation code.

How to validate this confirmation code with wso2is using SCIM 2?

In REST API there is an option to [validate code](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS590/apidocs/self-registration/#!/operations#SelfRegister#validateCodePost).

I tried REST API

```
curl -k -v -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "code": "84325529-8aa7-4851-8751-5980a7f2d9f7","properties": []}' "https://localhost:9443/api/identity/user/v1.0/validate-code"
```

it returns in case of invalid code

```
{
    "code": "18001",
    "message": "Bad Request",
    "description": "Invalid Code '84325529-8aa7-4851-8751-5980a7f2d9f7'"
}
```

in the case valid code it returns

```
{
    "code": "18001",
    "message": "Bad Request",
    "description": "Invalid Code '%s.'"
}
```

**no console error**

Validate code worked with [REST API work flow](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS590/apidocs/self-registration/#!/operations#SelfRegister#validateCodePost)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such SCIM APIs in WSO2 Identity Server to validate the confirmation codes. WSO2 Identity Server has a soap API (UserInformationRecoveryService-verifyConfirmationCode) and a REST API (/validate-code) that can fulfill your requirement.

You can find the SOAP API [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS580/User+Information+Recovery+Service#UserInformationRecoveryService-verifyConfirmationCode).

Comment: Thank you ,I tried REST API it returns  {
    "code": "18001",
    "message": "Bad Request",
    "description": "Invalid Code '%s.'"
},

Comment: Can you please attach the request you send? And if any error logs found in the carbon console, please attach them as well

Comment: According to the error logs, it says the confirmation code is empty. A valid response for an invalid code should be as Response is as follows:

{"code":"18001","message":"Bad Request","description":"Invalid Code '893245029-8aa7-3859-8859-123ru4555oa.'"}

Comment: Please follow this blog https://medium.com/@isurakarunaratne/self-user-registration-wso2-identity-server-14508083d65e and enable debug logs for the following components      log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.governance=DEBUG, 
log4j.logger.org.wso2.carbon.identity.recovery=DEBUG and please attach the debug logs

Comment: The code verification working with https://localhost:9443/api/identity/recovery/v0.9/set-password https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS590/apidocs/account-recovery/#!/operations#PasswordRecovery#setPasswordPost

Answer (score 1):

I am editing my answer here since I talked with the developers and I realised there is a different API that you need to use for validating the confirmation code: [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS511/apidocs/account-recovery/#!/operations#PasswordRecovery#validateCodePost).

So you need to send the following request:

```
curl -k -v -X POST -H "Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "code": "84325529-8aa7-4851-8751-5980a7f2d9f7","step": "UPDATE_PASSWORD","properties": []}' "https://localhost:9443/api/identity/recovery/v0.9/validate-code"
```

and the response should be

```
"HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted"
```

I tried it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Note: if you are using SCIM identity through a system like a self-managed  GitLab, [GitLab 15.3](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/08/22/gitlab-15-3-released/#user-scim-identity-visible-in-ui) (August 2022) offers a better integration:

> ### User SCIM identity visible in UI
>
> Previously, the SCIM identity for a user could only be accessed using the [SCIM API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/scim.html).
>
> Now, a user’s SCIM identity is visible to GitLab administrators in the **Identities** tab of the User list. With
> this, troubleshooting of SCIM-related issues is simplified. Administrators can validate what identity, if any, is
> being used for a specific account without requiring GitLab Support or an API query.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/#user-identities) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/294608).